# How can I get Business Address from Google Map Search Activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to launchGoogle Map's Search activity from my application to fetch address from user selected location. I could launch the search activity as per Google' guidelines, but I am having trouble in figuring out how to launch search activity for the result (in this case user selected location as address).

From below screen, User could pick "Peet's Coffee & Tea" as her location and control should return back to my application with its address. 
 [image]

Thanks for your time,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could achieve this by using Google PlacePicker API by doing so

```
try
    {
        PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
        Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(getActivity());
        // Start the Intent by requesting a result, identified by a request code.
        startActivityForResult(intent, ET_PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);

    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e)
    {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .getErrorDialog(e.getConnectionStatusCode(), getActivity(), 0);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Google Play Services is not available.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
```

and in ActivityResult() -

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == ET_PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST)
    {

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {

            final Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(getContext(), data);
            final CharSequence name = place.getName();
            final CharSequence address = place.getAddress();
            final String placeId = place.getId();
            //Your Code
        }
    }}
```